# Highlight rows if value in column A is x

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-formatting

How can I highlight a single row a color if text in `column A = X`

Using Row 4 as an example:
What i'm ultimately trying to get is if Cell in Column A is `= X` then change row color from `Range("B4:N4")` to  **Black** `And Text.Color` to **White** from `Range("F4:N4")`

Ultimately I would want it to be something like `Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))` but only color one row.

This is what i am working with so far.

```
Sub Header()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email Form")

    sht2.Activate
    sht2.Unprotect

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim WholeRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo 0

    With sht2
        Set rng = .Cells

        LastRow = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

        LastCol = rng.Find(What:="*", After:=rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

        'MsgBox wholerng.Address
        Set WholeRng = Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Rows

        For i = 4 To LastRow
            If sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value = "X" Then
            With WholeRng
                With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 1
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Font.Color = 0
                End With
            End With
            End If
        Next i

        Dim b As Boolean
        For Each rng In WholeRng.Rows
            If Not rng.Hidden Then
                If b Then rng.Interior.Color = 1
                b = Not b
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Set sht2 = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set WholeRng = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA Conditional Formatting.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Header()

    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim firstRow As Long, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = false
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email Form")
    firstRow = 4

    With sht2
        .Activate
        .Unprotect

        lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
        lastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column

        'black row, white text B:N
        With .Range(.Cells(firstRow, "B"), .Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
            'optionally remove any pre-existing CFRs
            .FormatConditions.Delete
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=UPPER($A4)=CHAR(88)")
                .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                .Font.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .SetFirstPriority
                .StopIfTrue = False
            End With
        End With
        'don't display values from B:E
        With .Range(.Cells(firstRow, "B"), .Cells(lastRow, "E"))
            With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=UPPER($A4)=CHAR(88)")
                .NumberFormat = ";;;"
            End With
        End With

        'I tnhink you want to reProtect the worksheet here
        .Protect
    End With


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your goal using Conditional Formatting:

You can create a condition for each format setting for the two different ranges.

Select one range at a time, then from the Home tab, create a New Conditional Formatting Rule, choose to Use a Formula and then enter a formula like:

```
=$A2="X"
```

Note that when using relative/mixed references in conditional formatting, it will be compared to the first cell in the range you are working with. I've selected range B2:N7 to apply formatting to, so the mixed reference needs to be created as it should apply to the B2 cell. You can't see it, but the reference automatically changes for all other cells in the same range, the same as if you were filling a formula across the rest of the range. For example, the formatting for the K5 cell will be dependent on the value in $A5 (because the column reference is fixed but the row reference is dynamic).

Then set the background colour or font colour you want for the range specified. This condition will check column A of the corresponding row.

[image: Img]

Comment: Thanks, im trying to get it in VBA code so it can be ran with some more code.

Answer (score 0):

I re-wrote some of your code and added comments to show you why. But by and large, I followed your original approach.

```
Sub Header()

    Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim IsBlack As Boolean, FillPattern As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long

'    Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email Form")
    Set Sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Taylor")
'    On Error GoTo 0                     ' this is the default: no need to set
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sht2
        .Activate                       ' no need to activate this sheet
        .Unprotect
        ' this is the whole sheet: Easier to refer to it as .Cells
        ' Set rng = .Cells
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'        LastRow = Rng.Find(What:="*", After:=Rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, _
'                           LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
'                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
'        LastCol = Rng.Find(What:="*", After:=Rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, _
'                           LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
'                           SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
'        MsgBox "Last row = " & LastRow & vbCr & _
'               "Last column = " & LastCol

        For R = 4 To LastRow
            IsBlack = Not CBool(StrComp(.Cells(R, 1).value, "X", vbTextCompare))
            FillPattern = CLng(Array(xlNone, xlSolid)(Abs(IsBlack)))
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, LastCol))
            With Rng.Interior
                If .Pattern <> FillPattern Then
                    .Pattern = FillPattern
                    If IsBlack Then
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
                    End If
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    Rng.Font.ColorIndex = Array(xlAutomatic, 2)(Abs(IsBlack))
                End If
            End With
        Next R
    End With

    ' VBA does this cleanup automatically at the end of the sub
'    Set sht2 = Nothing
'    Set Rng = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```